# uploading files to google appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, file-upload

I have deployed my application to google appengine.I have no idea how can I upload files to google appengine. Earlier I had been using *apachecommonns* library to upload files.Though not exactly clear why I can't use the same library to upload files here to google app server,I want to know how I can upload files to google app engine using *Java* ?

Comment: please check following answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6636554/upload-file-in-appengine-really-needed

Answer (score 0):

You can still [use commons file upload to parse the upload request](https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/java#fileforms) and then [use `FileService`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore) to write files to Blobstore.